# Font Boosting Issue in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, html, android-5.0-lollipop, font-size

We recently noticed font boosting issue in Android Lollipop OS. If user modifies font size in settings Menu, application is reloading if it is already running and all fonts are modified based on selected font size in device settings.

If we are setting below metatag viewport, issue is not exist in iOS and android OS < 5.0

> ```
> > <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,
> > maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
> ```

Is there any option to resolve this issue?????

Note :
1. This kind of issue is not available in iOS and Android < 5.0. 
2. There is no issue for thin application for Android >= 5.0 as well. (Only webpage is reloading whenever there is a change in device font settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is getting resolved by setting below value in webview. 
    **webView.getSettings().setTextZoom(100);**

Root cause: 
    For Android OS < 5.0 TextZoom is having default value as 100. But in Lollipop OS, value is taken from font settings in device if it is not overwritten in application. If we are setting textZoom as 100, font settings changes is not affecting application.